# Get Multiple columns in Result Set from sparql in Netbeans JTable

Tags: java, sparql, jena, protege

I am trying to select multiple columns in Jena result set and then binding the same to Java table.

When I select only one column, the result set is working fine but when I select two columns then the result set does not have any row although it has only columns:

Here is my Java code:

```
private void btnExecuteSPARQLActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        
        try 
        {           
            System.out.println("Executing SPARQL...");  // get the name list query
            String queryString;
            queryString = "PREFIX ssuet:<http://www.semanticweb.org/alinaanjum2/ontologies/2021/6/untitled-ontology-4#> "
                           + txtQuery.getText();

            com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet results = OpenOWL.ExecSparQl(queryString); //all method ExecSparQl from OpenOWL class
    
            ResultSetFormatter.out(results);

            // It creates and displays the table
            JTable table = new JTable(buildTableModel(results));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
           System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }                                                
    
    //CODE ADDITION BY ALINA ANJUM STARTED ON 03-AUGUST-2021
   public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet rs)
        throws SQLException {

         List<String> metaData = rs.getResultVars();

    // names of columns
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    int columnCount = metaData.size();
    
       System.out.println(columnCount);
       
    for (int column = 0; column <columnCount; column++) 
    {
        columnNames.add(metaData.get(column));
    }

    // data of the table
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
    
    while (rs.hasNext()) 
    {
        QuerySolution sol = rs.nextSolution();     
        
        Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
        
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnCount; columnIndex++) 
        {
            //vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
            String columnName = columnNames.get(columnIndex);   
            vector.add(sol.getLiteral(columnName).getString());
        }
        data.add(vector);
    }

    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

}
```

The following Query is Perfectly returning values:

```
SELECT (str(?x) as ?name)
WHERE {
   ?Person ssuet:hasname ?x.
}
```

The following Query is working fine in Protege but not returning values in Result Set in Java:

```
SELECT (str(?x) as ?name)
(str(?y) as ?phone)
WHERE {
   ?Person ssuet:hasname ?x.
?Person ssuet:hasPhoneNumber ?y.
}
```

Screen shot of the OutPut in Netbeans:

[image]

Results for 2nd Query in protege:

[image]

Comment: `com.hp.hpl.jena.query` -- this version of Jena is ancient. Jena is currently on version 4.2.0.

Comment: in addition, you should use Java 11, omit the `Vector` class, follow your own naming convention and use `hasName` (camel case style)

Comment: if your second query doesn't return anything, not even on the Netbeans console, then the data simply isn't the same as in Protege and the query doesn't match. Did you check it via a text editor? Or just print the triple via Jena API?

Comment: @UninformedUser can you share the complete guide about the newer version of Jena? I am new to this

Comment: just use Apache Jena with Maven (docs are online) and not such a 6 yaer old 3rd party project like https://github.com/softiecode/QueryExpansion if you don't need whatever they deliver as features. And they do nothing more than loading the ontology into an `OntModel` and then run the query. I'd suggest to do this on the native Jena code and use latest `4.2.0`

Answer (score 0):

`ResultSets` are iterators.

Calling `ResultSetFormatter.out(results)` exhausts the iterator (no more rows).

If you want to use the result twice, use `ResultSetFactory.makeRewindable` to get a result set that can be reset to the start.

Comment: right, none of the two quries will show as `JTable` - but afaik the question was also why the second query doesn't show any resultset at all, even not on the CLI - see the first screenshot, it returns a full table on the CLI but only the header for the second

Comment: thanks @AndyS, but the problem is in 2nd query. it's not even returning in ResultSetFormatter as well at UninformedUser said.